# What's best practice to make enums compatible in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have const enum which is something like:

```
const enum ComponentId {
    A = 0, 
    B, 
    C
}
```

I also have another const enum called BaseId which can be shared in multiple places, defined in the same way:

```
const enum BaseId {
    D = 100, 
    E, 
    F
}
```

The thing is, I want to be able to use BaseId in the places where ComponentId is used as well:

```
function operateComponent(id: ComponentId) // want to be able to use BaseId as well
```

Should I just do **id: ComponentId | BasedId**, but that way I need to change the code in lots of places. I am wondering what the best practice is to achieve this goal?

Comment: [check out this explanation of enums in TS](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/enums#changing-the-number-associated-with-a-number-enum) - if that is a viable solution in your case (can't tell without context) you can add values to `ComponentId` starting at 100 and completely leave out the `BaseId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first - you don't need `const` near enum, as it's TS construct, not variable

please take a look at this example if it solves the issue for you:

you need to create a union type, that will include both or more enums:

```
enum ComponentId {
  A = 0,
  B,
  C,
}

enum BaseId {
  D = 100,
  E,
  F
}

type ComponentIdOrBaseId = ComponentId | BaseId

const operateComponent = (data: ComponentIdOrBaseId) => {}

const x = operateComponent(ComponentId.A)
```

Another option would be to combine all values in single enum:

```
enum ComponentId {
  A = 0,
  B,
  C,
  D = 100,
  E,
  F
}

type ComponentIdOrBaseId = ComponentId

const operateComponent = (data: ComponentIdOrBaseId) => {}

const x = operateComponent(ComponentId.F)
```